# NSBundle bundleWithPath fails

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsbundle

I am trying to load a bundle using bundleWithPath but it always fails (returns nil)
I was wondering what can be teh reasons why it fails and what are the way to het more information about the error.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure may have many reasons: the file doesn't exist, the file exist but not in the path you are looking for. It has some different extention. Or the file at your path is not in correct bundle format. That's all I can tell you without code.

From the documentation:

`+bundleWithPath:`

Returns an `NSBundle` object that corresponds to the specified directory.

```
+ (NSBundle *)bundleWithPath:(NSString *)fullPath
```

Return Value: The `NSBundle` object that corresponds to `fullPath`, or `nil` if `fullPath` does not identify an accessible bundle directory.

Comment: I am so sorry, it was a taping mistake.